# How to convert byte array to a shapefile in Java

Tags: shapefile, java

I have a function that is calculating/creating Isogonic lines for certain area. This function returns array of type **byte[]**. I would like to convert this array into a shapefile (not single .shp file but the one with all the necessary files for projection (.prj, .dbf, .shp etc.).

So far this is my test file:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // Read the byte array from file
            byte[] byteArray = Files.readAllBytes(Path.of("C:\\development\\Test\\src\\output.bin"));

            // Specify the path for the output Shapefile
            String outputShapefile = "C:\\development\\Test\\src\\output.shp";

            // Create the Shapefile from the byte array
            createShapefileFromByteArray(byteArray, outputShapefile);

            System.out.println("Shapefile created successfully at " + outputShapefile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void createShapefileFromByteArray(byte[] byteArray, String outputShapefile) throws IOException {
        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputShapefile)) {
            fos.write(byteArray);
        }
    }
}
```

It just converts .shp file into byteArray and this byteArray can be then transformed into .shp file. But I need to create other files mentioned above So I need to use library for this.

Is there a library that supports this?
If yes, what methods to use?

I have found GeoTools and GDAL so far but was not able to implement it yet.

Comment: depending on what is in your `byte[]` GeoTools is capable of doing this and as it is written in Java is probably a better bet than GDAL. Please show us the code you have written so far and what you are stuck on.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: I did not created nothing In particular I just managed to get Already existing Shapefile turn it into byteArray and then back to .shp file but I have no idea how to create rest of the files. For this I used FileOutputStream not some methods from library that is why I wrote here - I do not see any particular method in GeoTools library

Comment: You'll be wanting a `ShapefileDataStore` - but this seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - could you describe what you are trying to do as well as what you have tried so far.

Comment: What I am trying to do - I have a method that will produce ByteArrayOutputStream containing Magnetic Variation Grid (grid represents some area divided into smaller cells where each cell represents magnetic variation value) and then I want to form Isogonic lines from this information (I haven't completed this part yet but it is not important). 

Now I want to make sure that I will be able to generate shapefile from produced ByteArrayOutputStream.

What I have done - I have found some random .shp file, converted it into byte[] and back. I tried to implement it by GeoTools but no luck so far.

Comment: So, converting .shp file into byte[] and back is pointless as I need to generate proper shapefile containing more files like (.shp, .prj, .dbf etc.). I am lost - I tried to experiment with ShapefileDataStore with help of AI but no proper results. SO if you could somehow provide me points to follow I will be more than happy. I am relatively new to this so I am still learning

Comment: I suggest you work through https://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/tutorial/feature/csv2shp.html (and possibly the other tutorials) - It sounds like you need to save your Isogonic lines as a shapefile - the byte array is irrelevant

Comment: Shapefile is a [published](https://www.esri.com/content/dam/esrisites/sitecore-archive/Files/Pdfs/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf) data standard. Note that your code does *not* create a valid shapefile, since shapefile is a collection of at least three files, with a fourth text block of coordinate reference info. A byte stream doesn't give you any benefit unless you are able to decode the geometry and attributes *and* are able to encode them again. There are a number of libraries that implement shapefiles; you merely need to pick one.